# switch temporarily to headless mode or runlevel 3?

Tags: server, 64-bit, headless

I've installed ubuntu 10.10 x86_64 desktop version, which defaults to Xorg login

I want to **temporarily** switch this machine to server mode, basically i *"suspect"* this entails setting to runlevel 3 and headless mode somewhere

what are the details of this? Also very important is how do i re enable desktop mode again?

Comment: there should be a really simple answer for this on linux, but it seems that ubuntu makes it really hard?

Comment: Have you tried the solutions given below? I see no comment from you.

Comment: you are right, i've added comments on each of the answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If for *headless* or *server mode* you mean without graphical interface, it is sufficient to stop `gdm`:

```
sudo stop gdm
```

so that you remain only with virtual consoles.

To enable again the graphical login, start `gdm`:

```
sudo start gdm
```

Be aware that this can make your network stop working.

To avoid this it is probably enough to set the connection as a *System connection* in network manager

Comment: Another option is to pre-empt network-manager by configuring networking through [/etc/network/interfaces](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man5/interfaces.5.html).

Comment: if i reboot the server it will still boot into gdm

Comment: So you should clarify what you means by "temporary" in your question. My solution works without rebooting. If you want to stand without graphics even after reboot you should follow the answer by @Lorem above.

Comment: thanks, i appreciate your answer. The reason i've added a bounty is because i was hoping someone would offer a solution using the actual runlevels; whatever scripts/interfaces uses ubuntu for them

Comment: I think it should be possible to use runlevels, but not in the default configuration. Doing some modifications to the files in `/etc/init` and to links in `/etc/rc*.d`, so that, say, runlevel 3 corresponds to all common services without `gdm`, you can simply use `telinit 3` to go to text-only mode. But I have not tested this, nor advices to do so.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK Ubuntu doesn't use the runlevel, in fact the `/etc/rc*.d` directory are the same. If your goal is to not run Xorg automatically just edit `/etc/default/grub` and modify the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

in

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash text"
```

then type:

```
sudo update-grub
```

to switch back delete "text" and re-run `sudo update-grub`

Comment: this might be the better option given the above requirements, however i shudder at the thought that to do this i need to tinker with grub

Comment: you could also add a custom grub menu item, so that you `update-grub` once and for all, and to switch to "headless" mode you only need to choose the correct item in the grub menu

Comment: that would be acceptable

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command:

```
sudo telinit 2
```

That'll make the system go to runlevel 3, if you want to get back to "normal" re-run the command like this:

```
sudo telinit 5
```

Comment: after running `sudo telinit 3` nothing happens. I reboot and i still get the X server login

Comment: ubuntu uses 2 as default graphical runlevel, and 1 as single user mode.

Comment: @enzotib, very non-SySV, but who cares right? so there is not a runlevel for headless server mode?